# Shortest decimal representations of rational numbers

Tags: c#

I want to to represent two numbers in `A/B` format,wWhere `A` and `B` are any integers. I want the decimal result in shortest format.

Examples:

- The shortest decimal representation of `3/28` is `"0.10(714285)"`.
- Decimal representation of `1/7` is `"0.(142857)"`

How can I do this with C#?

Comment: It looks like you're not asking for coding solution but rather an algorithm. I don't think this is the appropriate forum. Try the [Mathematics site](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @flem: The Mathematics site is for math students and professionals. Probably better not bother them with such trivialities. :)

Comment: Why is asking for an algorithm for converting rational numbers into a specific string representation off topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hopefully, someone can convert this to C# code:

```
def get_decimal(a, b):
    result = str(a / b) + '.'
    r = a % b
    remainders = []
    while r not in remainders:
        remainders.append(r)
        result += str(10 * r / b)
        r = 10 * r % b
    return result
```

Some tests:

```
>>> get_decimal(1, 7)
'0.142857'
>>> get_decimal(10, 7)
'1.428571'
>>> get_decimal(3, 28)
'0.10714285'
>>> get_decimal(99099167, 990000000)
'0.100100168'
```

If you need the parentheses to indicate the repeating set of digits, then something like this:

```
def get_decimal(a, b):
    result = str(a / b) + '.'
    r = a % b
    remainders = []
    digits = []
    while r not in remainders:
        remainders.append(r)
        digits.append(str(10 * r / b))
        r = 10 * r % b
    start = remainders.index(r)
    result += ''.join(digits[0:start]) + '(' + ''.join(digits[start:]) + ')'
    return result
```

Some tests:

```
>>> get_decimal(1, 7)
'0.(142857)'
>>> get_decimal(10, 7)
'1.(428571)'
>>> get_decimal(3, 28)
'0.10(714285)'
>>> get_decimal(99099167, 990000000)
'0.1001001(68)'
```

Comment: Does that work for `121 / 999`? Should produce `0.(121)`.

Comment: @COMEFROM Yes, `get_decimal(121, 999)` returns the string `0.(121)`.

Comment: Good, +1. Just didn't see it right a way. I should point out that what's done here is just good old long division applied to the remainder, probably taught at high or even primary level schools in many places.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get result upto 2 decimal places...For this you can use

```
double result = 0.142857; 
int decimalPlaces = 2;//for two decimal places
double multiplier = Math.Pow(10, Convert.ToDouble(decimalPlaces));
result =  Math.Ceiling(result * multiplier) / multiplier;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. From `3/28` OP wants `0.10(714285)` indicating the recurrence.